# ng-models not binding when ng-checked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

I have a Parent checkbox that gets checked when a child checkbox is clicked. I want this parent checkbox to in-turn bind with a third checkbox. But the 2 way binding is not working when the change is due to ng-checked. Here is the template:

```
<div><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="childCheckbox" ng-model="parentCheckbox" /> Parent Checkbox</div>
<div><input type="checkbox" ng-model="childCheckbox" /> Child Checkbox</div>
<div><input type="checkbox" ng-model="parentCheckbox" /> A third Checkbox binding with Parent Checkbox</div>
```

Here is the working sample in jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/Alien_time/vy5UM/1/

In order words, when parent checkbox is checked by clicking, the ng-model binds with the 3rd checkbox. But if the parent checkbox get checked due to ng-checked, the third checkbox is not updating the change. How can I achieve this in Angular?

Comment: ng-checked is just a conditional attribute, it doesn't ever modify the attached property. Is there a reason you don't just have all of these checkboxes using the same value as an ng-model? That seems to be the intention

Comment: Why you can't just add the `ng-checked="childCheckbox"` to 3rd checkbox?

Comment: @Artem Petrosian the example is a simplified version for a demo. But in my case, the 3rd checkbox is actually placed inside another ng-repeat where I am unable to add ng-checked option for that parent. Thats why I thought of placing the main parent checkbox outside and then bind this with the 3rd one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think it's possible without extra JS.

However, [I made a version that does use a bit of JS](http://jsfiddle.net/vy5UM/2/) and works fine.

```
<div><input type="checkbox" ng-click="clickOthers()" ng-model="childCheckbox" /> Child Checkbox</div>
```

(added to controller)

```
$scope.clickOthers = function () {
    $scope.parentCheckbox = $scope.childCheckbox;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Zeke. The JS method looks good. I will give that a try now.. :)

Comment: Thank you @ZekeSonxx Your JS method works well for static lists. However I am still having difficulty in adapting this code when the checkboxes are created using `ng-repeat` with dynamic `ng-models`. I have accepted this answer since your solution answers my above question. For my issue with Dynamic checkboxes, I have created a separate question more specific to that. Here is the link if you want to take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23468028/how-to-select-parent-checkbox-when-a-child-is-selected-inside-ng-repeat

Thanks again for your support so far. Much appreciated! :)