# How to select Parent Checkbox when a Child is selected inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am having a very hard time trying to figure out a solution for this. I have a checkbox group where the first checkbox is the parent and the following in that set will be child. I want the parent checkbox to be selected automatically if one of the child's checkbox is selected. Similarly parent needs to be get unchecked if no child is selected.

**Here is my jsfiddle example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Alien_time/PqTR7/3/

The main difficulty I am facing is because the checkboxes are created dynamically and it has dynamic ng-models for each. I have tried the following so far:

1) `ng-checked`: This doesnt work for me since ng-checked doesnt bind the value with ng-model. I need the ng-model of the parent to be updated as well since this is going to reflect in the main form.

2) JS solution: I thought js method will be the solution, but dont know how to add the js to controller as the ng-model is dynamically generated.

3) On other posts, there are some method that uses select all when parent is checked. But I couldnt find a solution for my approach since its the other way around where I only want the parent selected if one of the child is selected.

For my form, I need to have a different ng-model for each checkbox thats why I am using the `name` to create a dynamic ng-model name. **But I just couldnt figure out how to select the parent checkbox if a child is selected in this dynamic list.**

I have been stuck on this for 2 days and searched a lot on the net. Can you help me please?

Comment: You can use $watch and write you logic inside that as per your requirement. Like this - http://jsfiddle.net/PqTR7/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/PqTR7/4/) is the working solution based on your fiddle.

#### JS

```
$scope.select = function(index){
    if(index === 0){
        $scope.slaves.forEach(function(slave, ind){
            $scope.slaves[ind].isChecked = $scope.slaves[0].isChecked;
        });
    }
    else {
        var anyChild = false;
        for(var i = 1; i < $scope.slaves.length; i++){
            anyChild = anyChild || $scope.slaves[i].isChecked; 
        }
        $scope.slaves[0].isChecked = anyChild;
    }
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="slave in slaves">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="slave.isChecked" ng-click="select($index)" />
    {{slave.name}} -  {{ slave.description }}
</div>
```

To tell the truth I do not find the solution elegant -- you would be better off by encapsulating the logic of it in a custom directive.
Moreover it would be probably better to express `parent-child` relation by:

```
var parent = {
   ... // parent data
   childeren : [child_1, ... , child_N] // array of children
}
```

Comment: Interesting to see a solution without dom-manipulation. I will give this a try. Thank you so much..

Comment: I am actually going with your code in the end. I like this method and also it updates the ngmodel this way which is important to me. However when I was updating my project code with this, the ng-click is triggered 1 click slow. Meaning, when a checkbox is clicked, instead of passing 'true', an empty object is sent in the first click and when I click again (unchecking it), it is showing true. So click is off by 1.  I couldnt replicate this in jsfiddle since it works there. Obviously its not the problem with your snippet bust something else is causing this 1 click offset. V weird.

Comment: I was looking into it a bit more. I dont know if this 1 click delay is due to the directive passing the info between the controller and back. Anyhow, thank you so much @artur grzesiak. I was stuck on this for sometime and your answer helped me out. Cheers!

Comment: Hi @artur grzesiak I found something really strange. Your code works fine in jsfiddle but when I try the exact same code in my offline testing site, the parent checkbox isint getting selected when the first child option is checked. It is only getting selected from the second child's click. But if I have `var anyChild = true;` in `else` statement, the parent gets checked when the first child is selected but it doesnt get unchecked when the last child is unchecked. Does it make sense? I have no idea why it works fine in jsfiddle but the exact code in my offline server is delayed by 1.  :(

Answer (score 1):

A solution to this problem is to add a watch.

Add the following in your controller

```
$scope.$watch('checkboxData', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    var anyChecked = false;
    // see if any are checked
    $scope.slaves.reduce(function (pVal, cVal, idx, arr) {
        if (newValue[cVal.name]) anyChecked = anyChecked || newValue[cVal.name];
    });
    // replace the parent 'checked' in the model
    $scope.checkboxData['Parent'] = anyChecked;
}, true);
```

And add the following to your input elements.

```
ng-checked='checkboxData[slave.name]'
```

Comment: Doing dom-manipulation (`document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0]`) in controller logic is definitely a bad idea. Moreover it will not work if parent is not the zero-th input element on the page.

Comment: @Marvin Smit I tried it and it works perfect! However, when I used `$watchCollection` I was receiving the `$scope.$watchCollection is not a function` error. So I changed it to `$watch` and added `, true` at the end and it worked. Thank you heaps.

Comment: Although this method checks the Parent checkbox when child is clicked, the ng-model of parent isint updated, meaning its still showing 'false' for parent: http://jsfiddle.net/Alien_time/PqTR7/6/

Comment: Slaps myself. Like artur said; i shouldn't touch the view, but the model.